# How to use interface without retyping keys

Tags: typescript

In order to use auto-complete, I use an interface that has a hardcoded key and value type.
It works correctly but I think typing the key twice (such as 'title', 'header' in interface, and real typo obj) is tedious. Are there better ways to use an interface with generics?

This is my code.

```js
interface Itypo{
  title: CSSProperties;
  header:CSSProperties;
}

const typo: Itypo = {
  title: {
    fontFamily: "Roboto",
    fontSize: 100,
    lineHeight: 117,
  },
  header: {
    fontFamily: "Roboto",
    fontSize: 18,
    lineHeight: 22,
  },
};
```

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to key in `title` and `header`? Or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get around this repetition if you're using an interface with named properties. You need to type the property names in the `interface` declaration, and you need to type the property names in the object literal to specify their values.

You probably just want to keep doing that, but there is an alternative, which is to use a tuple type instead, perhaps even a named tuple:

```typescript
type Itypo = [title: CSSProperties, header: CSSProperties];

const typo: Itypo = [
  {
    fontFamily: "Roboto",
    fontSize: 100,
    lineHeight: 117,
  },
  {
    fontFamily: "Roboto",
    fontSize: 18,
    lineHeight: 22,
  }
];
```

Now `title` and `header` are positional (`title` in the first position and `header` in the second).

But while that saves the typing of `title` and `header`, it may suffer for a lack of clarity at the point where you're using `typo`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype):

```
type TypoKeys = 'title' | 'header';

// Or maybe this type
// type TypoKeys = 'title' | 'header' | string;

const typo: Record<TypoKeys, CSSProperties> = {
    title: {
        fontFamily: "Roboto",
        fontSize: 100,
        lineHeight: 117
    },
    header: {
        fontFamily: "Roboto",
        fontSize: 100,
        lineHeight: 117
    }
};
```